# -bash: ./geth: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: 16.04, bashrc, executable

There are many questions out there with the same title, however, I have checked the binary version and OS version. Both are same and thus asking this question here.

I have created a VM on Google cloud(ubuntu 16.04 LTS)and trying to install geth using binary file and facing the error.

```
-bash: ./geth: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

File version

```
> file geth

geth: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, ARM aarch64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1, for GNU/Linux 3.7.0, BuildID[sha1]=4b7c90f77d16087e2d4d36072864ba7585659fba, not stripped
```

OS version

```
> dpkg --print-architecture

amd64
```

Steps that I have followed

```
sudo tar -xvf <geth_tar_file>

sudo chmod +x geth

./geth version
```

So, my question is, what is cause of this error and how to resolve it?

Comment: You host architecture is *amd64*, and the binary is *aarch64*, so why the mystery?   It'll run if you use an arm64 server (not amd64), or you grab instead a amd64 binary for your existing server (ie. match binary to architecture of your server).

Comment: alright @guiverc, thanks. am new to Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file geth` says that geth is for "ARM aarch64" but you are on a AMD64 / x86-64 system.

You will have to find a geth package for AMD64 / x86-64.